Check whether CheckBox in GridView is checked or not in c# and ASP.Net
I need check whether CheckBox in GridView is checked or not in c# and ASP.Net and to check that all the checkboxes in my gridview are selected, some are selected and some are not, according to a predefined condition, the previous column in the gridview must equal OK.
If all the checkboxes of the gridview are selected I have to continue to execution of the page, otherwise if also even if only one checkbox is not selected I have to block the execution of the page..
I don't have error but the check whether CheckBox in GridView is checked not working.
My code below.
.aspx
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBxHeader"
            AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkBxHeader_CheckedChanged" runat="server" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

.cs
protected void chkBxHeader_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkRow = (row.FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);

                if (chkRow.Checked)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Alert", "alert('KO');", true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Skipped exception! " + ex);
    }
}


Ok, you code logic is not quite correct.
Also, do you really want the test/check to occur when the user clicks on the check box, or would it not be better to have the user select/check each check box, and then have one final submit on the page?
Also, often such logic is better done with client-side code.
However, for now let's go with server-side code.
Hence, your code logic can look like this:
Here is my sample GridView markup:
        <asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server"
                            OnCheckedChanged="chkActive_CheckedChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="true"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

And, here is the code behind:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL =
            "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";
        GVHotels.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        GVHotels.DataBind();    

    }


    protected void chkActive_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bool AllChecked = true;

        foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GVHotels.Rows)
        {
            if (gRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkActive = (CheckBox)gRow.FindControl("chkActive");

                if (chkActive.Checked == false)
                {
                    AllChecked = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!AllChecked)
        {
            string sJava = "alert('More rows to be checked');";

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "mymsg", sJava, true);
            return;
        }

        // if we get here then all rows are checked.
        // code and logic follows when all rows are checked.

    }

So, if some rows are not checked, then we exit the routine, and the code for all code checked will not run.
